# Unable to import all tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to import all the tables of sequel server using sqoop

```
sqoop import-all-tables  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://40.112.254.xxx;database=IDSTC" --username DbReader
 --password Plexus123! --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver  --target-dir
 '/landing/IDSTC
```

it is showing me following error is there any modifications i have to do to my command

> 16/04/10 01:12:17 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version:
>   1.4.5.2.2.9.1-8
>       16/04/10 01:12:17 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
>       16/04/10 01:12:17 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: all-tables
>       16/04/10 01:12:17 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --connect
>       16/04/10 01:12:17 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: jdbc:sqlserver://40.112.254.104;database=IDSTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`sqoop import-all-tables  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://40.112.254.xxx;database=IDSTC" --username DbReader --password Plexus123! --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver  --warehouse-dir /landing/IDSTC`

Comment: Yes I was bit late. But it worked for me. Thank you dev